# Tensorflow transformer with CNN

Tags: tensorflow, ocr, transformer-model, conv-neural-network

I try to implement OCR in tensorflow. I would like to use transformer in combination with CNN for input image. I try this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer and now I need to remake it to use CNN for the input image. Do you know any implementations or tutorials? Because I can't find anything. I am new to tensorflow so I don't have an idea how to exchange input sentence instead of input image. Thank you

Comment: Exactly how do you want to combine a transformer with a CNN? They are generally thought of as two different types of neural networks. Hybrids are possible though.